# How to list all files/ folders of sdcard/external storage using react-native-fs

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, react-native-fs

my question is how can I show or aleast get all contents in sdcard r external storage (all files and all folders) in react native using react-native-fs library.

Comment: You have tagged iOS. You cannot do this on iOS.

Comment: Can I access local storage of IOS from react native?

Comment: You can use something like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-document-picker) that wraps the native `UIDocumentPickerViewController` to ask the user to select a file from local or cloud storage.